# In SimCity Deluxe, why do my Sims constantly ask for water?

Tags: simcity-deluxe

I'm having trouble keeping my cities water supply up. I can build some pumping-stations and water-towers which solves the problem, but only for a very short period of time.

I have now reached a point where almost the entire coastline is covered with pumping-stations and I also have truckloads of water-towers. I'm starting to think it is a bug but maybe somebody sees some obvious flaw with my water-pipe layout:

[image: SimCity water pipes]

This is how the city looks like:

[image: Simcity town]

There are some high-density residential and industrial zones, but nothing that would require *that* amount of pumping-stations? There must be about 120-180 pumping-stations on that map.

Comment: I played SimCity on PC -- never played it on iPad.  Wasn't there a distillation facility to provide clean water?  Maybe that's what you're missing?

Comment: Yeah, I have the water treatment plant. It's hidden behind the menu on the right. Actually, water pollutions is fine (no complaints there). But the water seems to get sucked up by some *monster-sponge* faster than I can pump it to my Sims.

Comment: From what I remember, all I had to do is make sure the water covers all the area below any type of zone -- no tricks beyond that, at least in SC4.

Comment: Dang, that's a lot of water towers.

Comment: If this game is anything like SC4 (and it certainly *looks* similar), then two things: Once you have enough demand to use pumps, then there's no reason to use towers - pumps are far more efficient for larger cities. Second, don't connect to the dirty industries at all. It does nothing but reduce the risk of fire slightly (I think) while draining a large amount of water. Also, never build water supplies inside polluted areas. For 148k population, you should never need to use *so many* pumps. Of course all of the above comes from SC4, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Why not pack that into an answer :)
@Yi Jiang: My problem is, that I have almost no place left to build pumps. So I switched to towers. 
@BeemerGuy: The water covers all the area, so I really think it's a bug in the iPad version of the game.. maybe they set some decimal point wrong and only 1/10 of the supposed water amount is being "generated"..

Comment: Just to clear things up for people who have only played the PC versions, Simcity Deluxe is Simcity 3 mechanics with Simcity 4 graphics.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue? I just bought simcity dlx on iPad (May 2011) and I have the same issue. B

Comment: @Ben Nope, sadly not. I was hoping for a patch/update but that never arrived.

Comment: Do you have the "[drink 30 gallons of water a day for better health](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2308/is-there-any-evidence-that-people-need-to-drink-8-glasses-of-water-a-day)" social policy enabled?

Comment: @Nick T: I guess that's exactly what my Sims do (You're joking, right? Just asking because you never know what crazy stuff Game-Designers implement in their games)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there's nothing wrong with the water-supply and as comments to the question suggest, a city of this size should never require that many pumps and water-towers. So I'll try to answer this question myself and claim that it's a bug.

I did some searches and as it seems I'm not the only one with this problem. Here's a [forum post](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=76216&page=8#post1494900) and here's [another one](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1066678) suggesting that there is indeed a bug regarding water supply.
So I guess the only hope is waiting for an upcoming patch to fix this.

Comment: I'm here to try and solve this exact issue. I'm 99.9% certain it's a bug as - like you - my maps ends up covered in pumps, towers and pipes and I still get the 'not enough water' message... CONSTANTLY. Seriously, it doesn't let up does it? It's a bug. It has to be.

Comment: Definitely a bug. Further confirmed by many reviewers on the App Store, and my own experience playing versions where this bug does *not* occur on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to renew the old pumping stations, the old ones get inefficient and lose capacity. Agree, it is hard to play with this bug or issue.

Comment: Yes, the description of the pumping station states something along these lines. I didn't find a way to identify old pumping stations however. I also tried to replace several pumping stations that I built a while ago with new ones but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this gameplay feature exists in the iPad version, but if you have road/water links to the outside and are trading water, you might just be pumping out too much.